# Android widget add dynamically gradient to background

Tags: android

I need to add a gradient to my View `ImageView`. I was just using this code:

```
    ShapeDrawable sd = new ShapeDrawable(new RectShape());
    sd.getPaint().setShader(new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 300, color, color, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT));

    mUpdateViews.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.imageview, ((BitmapDrawable)sd).getBitmap());
```

But the problem is:

> "Cannot cast from ShapeDrawable to BitmapDrawable"

Is it possible to load a gradient from the code, and not from an XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot cast `ShapeDrawable` to `BitmapDrawable`:

```
java.lang.Object
   ↳ android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
       ↳ android.graphics.drawable.ShapeDrawable
```

vs

```
java.lang.Object
   ↳ android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
       ↳ android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable
```

so you'd be able to cast to Drawable only as this is the only (aside from Object) common functionality shared by these two classes.

> Is it possible to load a gradient from the code, and not from an XML?

if by "load" you mean create, then there's bunch of `createFrom...()` methods but at the moment you may want to stick to XML for better flexibility.

Comment: OK I just find a way to create it, only need a canvas/bitmap pairs and then draw it to the background. thanks:)